# What algorithm can I use to produce 'Random' value?

Tags: algorithm

Say I have 4 possible results and the probabilities of each result appearing are

```
1 = 10%
2 = 20%
3 = 30%
4 = 40%
```

I'd like to write a method like GetRandomValue which if called 1000 times would return

```
1 x 100 times
2 x 200 times
3 x 300 times
4 x 400 times
```

Whats the name of an algorithm which would produce such results?

Comment: Can you explain better you problem?

Comment: Infinitely repeating the sequence (1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4) matches the requirements you gave *exactly*. But that's not what you want, is it? Then what do you want? And why? Does it have to just look random? Does it have to be unguessable by an attacker?

Comment: @svick - This would be for a game so an attack wouldn't be a problem. I just needs to look random.

Comment: What language are you using? Writing your own random generation function seems like a lot of work for a game since most programming languages supply such a function which is usually good enough for those purposes.

Comment: @DeCaf - This will must likely be written in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your case you can generate a random number (int) within `1..10` and if it's `1` then select `1`, if it's between `2-3` select 2 and if it's between `4..6` select `3` and if is between `7..10` select `4`.

In all if you have some probabilities which sum to 1, you can have a random number within (0,1) distribute your generated result to related value (I simplified in your case within 1..10).

Comment: And how do you generate that random value?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. @svivk - Generating the random between 1 and 10 isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random number you would use the `Random` class of .Net.

Something like the following would accomplish what you requested:

```cs
public class MyRandom
{
   private Random m_rand = new Random();

   public int GetNextValue()
   {         
      // Gets a random value between 0-9 with equal probability
      // and converts it to a number between 1-4 with the probablities requested.
      switch (m_rand.Next(0, 9))
      {
         case 0:
            return 1;
         case 1: case 2:
            return 2;
         case 3: case 4: case 5:
            return 3;
         default:
            return 4;               
      }    
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting usage of the `case` statement!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want those probabilities in the long run, you can just get values by randomly selecting one element from the array {1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4}.

If you however need to retrieve exactly 1000 elements, in those specific quantities, you can try something like this (not C#, but shouldn't be a problem):

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;
class Thing{

    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> counts=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int totalCount;

    public void set(int i, int count){    
        numbers.add(i);
        counts.add(count);
        totalCount+=count;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        if (totalCount==0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        double pos = r.nextDouble();

        double z = 0;
        int index = 0;

        //we select elements using their remaining counts for probabilities
        for (; index<counts.size(); index++){
            z += counts.get(index) / ((double)totalCount);
            if (pos<z)
                break;
        }

        int result = numbers.get(index);

        counts.set( index , counts.get(index)-1);
        if (counts.get(index)==0){
            counts.remove(index);
            numbers.remove(index);
        }
        totalCount--;

        return result;    
    }

}    

class Test{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Thing t = new Thing(){{
            set(1,100);
            set(2,200);
            set(3,300);
            set(4,400);
        }};

        int[]hist=new int[4];
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            int value = t.getValue();
            System.out.print(value);
            hist[value-1]++;
        }
        System.out.println();        

        double sum=0;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) sum+=hist[i];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            System.out.printf("%d: %d values, %f%%\n",i+1,hist[i], (100*hist[i]/sum));

    }

}
```